# Using anchor tag to open a mailto and invoke a URL

Tags: html, anchor, href, mailto

With one of my requirements i need to open up the default mailing client with invoking a call to a service, this needs to be accomplished using anchor tags or purely html, the constraint is that we can not use javascript for the same.
Does anyone have any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: What's wrong with using `<a href="mailto:..."></a>` ?

Comment: with mailto i need to invoke a URL

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment on one of the answers below: Without Javascript you cannot apply two click events to an object. To achieve what you want you require the use of a scripting language.

Answer (score 41):

try this:

```
<a href="mailto:test@test.com">Click to Mail</a>
```

This will open default mailing client.

**Edit :**
You may use onClick function to open new window and call you webservice url in it.like

```
<a href="mailto:test@test.com" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('your WS URL');">Click to Mail</a>
```

Comment: Yes this is only working to open mail client but also i need to invoke a URL

Comment: @vaibhav without javascript an anchor tag can only have a single click action. It cannot perform two things at once.

Comment: @gvee is right. you need to use JavaScript to do both thing in one click.

Comment: this is a part of a mail which my program sends and all mailing clients DONOT support javascript hence the limitation is to use HTML tags only

Comment: @vaibhav i have add some code. it will use onCick event to call your ws by passing url to new window.

Comment: @Yagnesh `onClick` is a javascript event ;-)

Comment: @gvee than you should think about to place two link.

Answer (score 5):

you can use like this

```
<a href="mailto:me@domain.com?subject=Call me&body=dummy mail:">
  touch here</a>
```

try it

Comment: This would just open up the mail client i need to invoke a ws as well on the click

Comment: @vaibhav better use jscript with it

Answer (score 0):

If you feel very very daring (and don't mind a horrible hack), you can try if

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=mailto:foo@bar.baz" />
```

on your service page helps you. My brief check in FF suggests that since the new target starts an external program, the page doesn't go elsewhere. This might require some reshuffling of your service, depending on where exactly you want to spawn the mail window.